# Video Show First Frame Only on One Computer

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I have some video files that are only showing the first frame in VLC. The audio plays fine. If I copy the files onto a different computer, they plays. If I use another player, they plays (tried it with Windows Media Player and the Win 10 Movies app). Any ideas on why VLC can't play them right, just on one computer?

Edit: this question was marked as too broad? I don't know what other information I can add. If you know what info may help, please ask.

Edit 2: Upgrading VLC fixed it. Still doesn't help me understand why it was not playing, but oh well.

```
File Extension: mp4
Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
Resolution: 640x386
Display resolution: 640x360
Frame rate: 4
Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV
```

Comment: The solution in https://superuser.com/questions/468880/vlc-2-frozen-stuck-on-first-frame-of-avi-video did not work for me.